# Fill NULL value with progressive row_number over partition function

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, row-number, database-partitioning

**What I have**

From the following #`MyTable` I just have `Name` and `Number` columns.

My goal is to fill the valus where Number = NULL with a progressive number and get the values I have wrote into the `Desidered_col` column.

```
+------+--------+---------------+
| Name | Number | Desidered_col |
+------+--------+---------------+
| John | 1      |             1 |
| John | 2      |             2 |
| John | 3      |             3 |
| John | NULL   |             4 |
| John | NULL   |             5 |
| John | 6      |             6 |
| Mike | 1      |             1 |
| Mike | 2      |             2 |
| Mike | NULL   |             3 |
| Mike | 4      |             4 |
| Mike | 5      |             5 |
| Mike | 6      |             6 |
+------+--------+---------------+
```

**What I have tried**

I have tried with the following query

```
SELECT Name, Number, row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY [Name] ORDER BY Number ASC) AS rn
FROM #MyTable
```

but it put all the NULL values first and then count the rows.
How can I fill the empty values?

**Why I don't think is a duplicate question**

I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345065/sql-query-replace-null-value-in-a-row-with-a-value-from-the-previous-known-value) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39655637/sql-server-behaviour-of-row-number-partition-by-null-value) but I don't think it is duplicate because they don't consider the `PARTITION BY` construct.

---

This is the script to create and populate the table

```
SELECT * 
INTO #MyTable
FROM (
    SELECT 'John' AS [Name], 1 AS [Number], 1 AS [Desidered_col] UNION ALL
    SELECT 'John' AS [Name], 2 AS [Number], 2 AS [Desidered_col] UNION ALL
    SELECT 'John' AS [Name], 3 AS [Number], 3 AS [Desidered_col] UNION ALL
    SELECT 'John' AS [Name], NULL AS [Number], 4 AS [Desidered_col] UNION ALL
    SELECT 'John' AS [Name], NULL AS [Number], 5 AS [Desidered_col] UNION ALL
    SELECT 'John' AS [Name], 6 AS [Number], 6 AS [Desidered_col] UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Mike' AS [Name], 1 AS [Number], 1 AS [Desidered_col] UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Mike' AS [Name], 2 AS [Number], 2 AS [Desidered_col] UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Mike' AS [Name], NULL AS [Number], 3 AS [Desidered_col] UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Mike' AS [Name], 4 AS [Number], 4 AS [Desidered_col] UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Mike' AS [Name], 5 AS [Number], 5 AS [Desidered_col] UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Mike' AS [Name], 6 AS [Number], 6 AS [Desidered_col]
) A
```

Comment: So the null must fill the gaps between the numbers? or can you assign new numbers to all the rows? I mean can you make Jhon - 6 become Jhon - 4 and then the two NULL become 5 and 6 ?

Comment: Your desired output is impossible to achieve given the table structure. You MUST have something to use an order in the data and you don't have that. Remember that be definition a table is an unordered set. We give meaning to the order with an order by clause. You can't do that an keep your rows in the same order as you displayed.

Comment: how do you know that the gaps always cover the missing sequences, between John,3 and John,6 what makes you think that you will have 2 items all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query is a bit complicated but seems to return your expected result. The only case it may be wrong is when someone does not have `Number = 1`.

The idea is that you must find gaps between numbers and count how many null values can be used to fill them.

**Sample data**

```
create table #myTable (
    [Name] varchar(20)
    , [Number] int
)

insert into #myTable
insert into #myTable
SELECT 'John' AS [Name], 1 AS [Number] UNION ALL
SELECT 'John' AS [Name], 2 AS [Number]UNION ALL
SELECT 'John' AS [Name], 3 AS [Number] UNION ALL
SELECT 'John' AS [Name], NULL AS [Number] UNION ALL
SELECT 'John' AS [Name], NULL AS [Number] UNION ALL
SELECT 'John' AS [Name], 6 AS [Number] UNION ALL
SELECT 'Mike' AS [Name], 1 AS [Number] UNION ALL
SELECT 'Mike' AS [Name], 2 AS [Number] UNION ALL
SELECT 'Mike' AS [Name], NULL AS [Number] UNION ALL
SELECT 'Mike' AS [Name], 4 AS [Number] UNION ALL
SELECT 'Mike' AS [Name], 5 AS [Number] UNION ALL
SELECT 'Mike' AS [Name], 6 AS [Number]
```

**Query**

```
;with gaps_between_numbers as (
    select
        t.Name, cnt = t.nextNum - t.Number - 1, dr = dense_rank() over (partition by t.Name order by t.Number)
        , rn = row_number() over (partition by t.Name order by t.Number)
    from (
        select 
            Name, Number, nextNum = isnull(lead(Number) over (partition by Name order by number), Number + 1)
        from 
            #myTable
        where
            Number is not null
    ) t
    join master.dbo.spt_values v on t.nextNum - t.Number - 1 > v.number
    where
        t.nextNum - t.Number > 1
        and v.type = 'P'
)
, ordering_nulls as (
    select
        t.Name, dr = isnull(q.dr, 2147483647)
    from (
        select
            Name, rn = row_number() over (partition by Name order by (select 1))
        from
            #myTable
        where 
            Number is null
    ) t
    left join gaps_between_numbers q on t.Name = q.Name and t.rn = q.rn
)
, ordering_not_null_numbers as (
    select
        Name, Number, rn = dense_rank() over (partition by Name order by gr)
    from (
        select
            Name, Number, gr = sum(lg) over (partition by Name order by Number)
        from (
            select
                Name, Number, lg = iif(Number - lag(Number) over (partition by Name order by Number) = 1, 0, 1)
            from
                #myTable
            where
                Number is not null
        ) t
    ) t
)

select
    Name, Number
    , Desidered_col = row_number() over (partition by Name order by rn, isnull(Number, 2147483647))
from (
    select * from ordering_not_null_numbers
    union all
    select Name, null, dr from ordering_nulls   
) t
```

CTE `gaps_between_numbers` is seeking for numbers that are not consecutive. `Number` difference between current and next row shows how many NULL values can be used to fill the gaps. Then `master.dbo.spt_values` is used to multiply each row by that amount. In `gaps_between_numbers` `dr` column is gap number and `cnt` is amount of NULL values that need to used.

`ordering_nulls` orders only NULL values and is joined with CTE `gaps_between_numbers`to know in which position each row should appear.

`ordering_not_null_numbers` orders values that are not NULL. Consecutive Numbers will have same row number

And last step is to union CTE's `ordering_not_null_numbers` and `ordering_nulls` and make desired ordering

[Rextester DEMO](http://rextester.com/GPRI6027)

Answer (score 1):

You could also assign the new ranking based on Desidered_col using `row_number()` function with `ORDER BY` clause (`select 1 or select null`)

```
select *, 
        row_number() over (partition by Name order by (select 1)) New_Desidered_col 
from #MyTable
```

Comment: This would produce an inconsistent order. It could even change between queries.

Comment: @SeanLange lock hints might prevent the case where order will change between query.

Comment: How is a lock hint going to ensure consistent ordering? If it "works" it is only temporary. There is one and only one way to ensure the order of rows in a query, using a order by clause.

Answer (score 1):

In order to do this, you need a column that specifies the order of the rows in the table.  You can do this using the `identity()` function:

```
SELECT identity(int, 1, 1) as MyTableId, a.* 
INTO #MyTable
. . .
```

I'm pretty sure SQL Server will follow the ordering of a `values()` statement and in practice will follow the ordering of a `union all`.  You can explicitly put this column in each row, if you prefer.

Then you can use this to assign your value:

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by name order by mytableid) as desired_col
from #MyTable
```

Comment: I believe the select is only to construct the test case. So you cant add the MyTableId unless you do an `ALTER TABLE`